# What's the correct way to retain objects in nested blocks

Tags: ios, multithreading, thread-safety, objective-c-blocks

I want to download image for each row in a table view, so I wrote a method to do this by using block.

I thought the indexPath and tableView may be not copied by the completion block, because they are used in an If-Statement. So I retain them before the completion block excute.

and the code is:

```
- (void)downloadImageAtURL:(NSString *)imageURL name:(NSString *)name serial:(BOOL)serial forTableView:(UITableView *)tableView indexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSMutableDictionary *cachedImagesOfURLs = self.cachedImagesOfURLs;

    UITableView *strongTableView = [tableView retain];
    NSIndexPath *strongIndexPath = [indexPath retain];

    [self.downloadManager downloadImageAtURL:imageURL
                                  identifier:[self identifierForIndexPath:indexPath]
                                      serial:serial
                                  completion:^(UIImage *image) {
                                      if (image) {
                                          [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
                                              [cachedImagesOfURLs setObject:image forKey:imageURL];

                                              id cell = [strongTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:strongIndexPath];
                                              if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(didDownloadImage:withName:)]) {
                                                  [cell didDownloadImage:image withName:name];
                                              }
                                          }];
                                      }

                                      [strongTableView release];
                                      [strongIndexPath release];
                                  }];
}
```

But the result is, when completion block excute and try to create a block and run it in main thread, it crash. The debugger print "**-[XXX cellForRowAtIndexPath:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance**". I seems that tableView and indexPath are deallocated.

But I don't know why, I have tried to retain them. Can somebody tell me how to prevent this crash happend? thank you very much!

Comment: But is it required to retain this?Did you tried the method variables directly in the blocks?I think it may work

Comment: The block copies the variables it needs.  No need for explicit retains.  Just refrain from referring to self.downloadManager within the block.

Comment: You should really switch over to ARC!

Comment: @Till Yep...I really think so. But I have to support iOS 4.3, and iOS 4.3 SDK not supports weak property. I will use ARC When my deployment target upgrade to iOS 5...

Comment: You can use unsafe_unretained on iOS4.3, so ARC is perfectly possible on that OS - just not with all of its features.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is enough

```
- (void)downloadImageAtURL:(NSString *)imageURL name:(NSString *)name serial:(BOOL)serial forTableView:(UITableView *)tableView indexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSMutableDictionary *cachedImagesOfURLs = self.cachedImagesOfURLs;

    [self.downloadManager downloadImageAtURL:imageURL
                                  identifier:[self identifierForIndexPath:indexPath]
                                      serial:serial
                                  completion:^(UIImage *image) {
                                      if (image) {
                                              [cachedImagesOfURLs setObject:image forKey:imageURL];

                                              id cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
                                              if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(didDownloadImage:withName:)]) {
                                                  [cell didDownloadImage:image withName:name];
                                              }
                                      }
                                  }];
}
```

Comment: Probably don't need to addOperation to mainQueue, the completion block itself probably runs on the main thread.

Comment: "the completion block itself probably runs on the main thread" what makes you think that?

Comment: @newacct, I'm not sure that it does, but if I were writing a "download manager", like NSURLConnection, I'd invoke the block on the main thread.  I'd tell my callers that the completion block may be used to update the UI, so I'd invoke it on the main as a convenience.

Comment: @LithuT.V the comletion block not runs on main thread, it runs on the thread it started download. And I think the issue is not caused by this. But thank you all the same.

Comment: @danh You are right. I should run the completion block on main thread. But the question is not about this.

Comment: @danh Yes, I control the code. I have checked the code, make sure the completion block is copied. But still not resolve the problem.

Comment: So dropping the retains doesn't fix your problem?  Then the problem is somewhere else.  You should leave the retains out.  The block will capture the variables you refer to within it.

Comment: please cut/paste the complete log message on the crash.  to bump your reputation so we can chat.

Comment: @danh OK, I will try...but it may take a long time. Thanks all the same.

Answer (score 0):

Even less code.  Not sure how the bits of code you refer to work, but from the names, I'd guess the following is sufficient:

```
- (void)downloadImageAtURL:(NSString *)imageURL name:(NSString *)name serial:(BOOL)serial forTableView:(UITableView *)tableView indexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSMutableDictionary *cachedImagesOfURLs = self.cachedImagesOfURLs;

    [self.downloadManager downloadImageAtURL:imageURL identifier:[self identifierForIndexPath:indexPath] serial:serial completion:^(UIImage *image) {
        if (image) {
            [cachedImagesOfURLs setObject:image forKey:imageURL];
            id cell = [strongTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:strongIndexPath];
            if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(didDownloadImage:withName:)]) {
                [cell didDownloadImage:image withName:name];
            }
        }
    }];
}
```